# Calculate the value of a function for given coordinates

Tags: python, equation, derivative, taylor-series

I am new here. I want to write a neat litte program to check the solutions of my exam preparations as my professor didnt provide any. For a non- linear differential equation f I want to find the 1st Taylor polynomial. Therefore I take the derivative of f in respect to every variable.
Now my problem:
I have to calculate the value of each derivative for a certain given point. How can I do that for such complex expressions that are just stored in a variable and not explicitly known, as they are calculated?

This is what i do now, without evaluating:

```
f = input('Enter function: ')
fy1 = diff(f,y1)
fy = diff(f,y)
fu2 = diff(f,u2)
fu1 = diff(f,u1)
fu = diff(f,u)
```

I tried this function as I hoped it would recognize the variables in f automatically:

```
def calculate(f,y1,y,u2,u1,u):
    return f

...

fy1 = calculate(diff(f,y1),0,-1,0,0,-4)
fy = calculate(diff(f,y),0,-1,0,0,-4)
fu2 = calculate(diff(f,u2),0,-1,0,0,-4)
fu1 = calculate(diff(f,u1),0,-1,0,0,-4)
fu = calculate(diff(f,u),0,-1,0,0,-4)
```

Edit:

I tried out something else:
For f= -5*y*y1+4*y-u (y1 is the derivative of y)
fy1 is the derivative of f in respect to y1:

```
fy1= diff(f, y1)
fy1.subs([(y1,0),(y,-1),(u2,0),(u1,0),(u,-4)])
print("{}".format(fy1))
```

But subs() didnt substitute any values  as the output was the following:

```
-5*y
```

I guess it has something to so with the variables being defined as sympy symbols?

```
y1 = symbols('y1')
y = symbols('y')
u2 = symbols('u2')
u1 = symbols('u1')
u = symbols('u')
```

But I need that for the sympy diff()-function

Comment: I feel the definition of the problem is rather unclear. A toy (but more complete) example may help. Is your input expression/output result numerical? Or expected to be symbolic?

Comment: Can you give an example for the diff equation f? I think what you are looking for can be done with [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html)

Comment: ok, to provide some context:
this a specific part of control engineering.
u is an input signal (e.g. pressing the asselerator) and y is the output signal (e.g. the speed of the car)
To describe such a control system, we use diferential equations. Normally, they are non linear, but at a certain point (a given speed) we can say it is linear. So we want to calculate the first taylor polynomial (or taylor polynomial of 1st degree, I dont know how to call it in english) as this is a linear approximation. Therefore I have to calculate the derivative of the equation for each variable at said point

Comment: f = -5*y*y1+4*y-u  //y1 is the derivative of y

Answer (score 0):

My solution for now is almost what I wrote in my first edit. What I didnt realize was that the substitution is not permanent and I had to store the solution in an extra variable.
Here is the complete program. I am open for suggestions to improve it an all aspects.

```
from sympy import diff, symbols

again = True

while(again):

    y1 = symbols('y1')
    y = symbols('y')
    u2 = symbols('u2')
    u1 = symbols('u1')
    u = symbols('u')
    
    f = input('Enter function: ')
    
    fy1= diff(f, y1)
    res_fy1 = fy1.subs([(y1,0),(y,-1),(u2,0),(u1,0),(u,-4)])
    print("{}".format(res_fy1))
    
    fy= diff(f, y)
    res_fy = fy.subs([(y1,0),(y,-1),(u2,0),(u1,0),(u,-4)])
    
    fu2= diff(f, u2)
    res_fu2 = fu2.subs([(y1,0),(y,-1),(u2,0),(u1,0),(u,-4)])
    
    fu1= diff(f, u1)
    res_fu1 = fu1.subs([(y1,0),(y,-1),(u2,0),(u1,0),(u,-4)])
    
    fu= diff(f, u)
    res_fu = fu.subs([(y1,0),(y,-1),(u2,0),(u1,0),(u,-4)])
    
    print('delta_y2 + (' + str(res_fy1) + ')*delta_y1 + (' + str(res_fy) + ')*delta_y + (' + str(res_fu2) + ')*delta_u2 + (' + str(res_fu1) + ')*delta_u1 + (' + str(res_fu) + ')*delta_u')      
    
    wrongInput = True    
    while (wrongInput):
        i = input('Another function? [y/n] ')
    
        if (i == 'n'):
            again = False
            wrongInput = False
    
        elif (i == 'y'):
            wrongInput = False
        
        else:
            print('Wrong Input!')
```